# Sql, compare row values against average of rows in that column

Tags: mysql, sql

So I was quite surprised that I wasn't able to find an answer after much googling so here goes. Given the below query which joins data from 3 tables and aggregates data on the store_id's. I want an additional column that compares the profit of that row against the average of the profit column. I've added the index column to illustrate how it should look. Row 1 would be 500 / 500 (avg. of profit column) etc.

````
SELECT 
    region, store_id, SUM(q1.revenue), SUM(q1.profit) as 'profit', 
    SUM(q1.profit) / SUM(revenue) * 100 as 'percentage'
FROM ( SELECT
    regions.region_name as 'region', s.store_id,
    s.revenue as 'revenue', (s.revenue - s.costs) as 'profit'
FROM
    store_sales s
    JOIN stores ON s.store_id = stores.store_id
    JOIN regions ON stores.store_id = regions.store_id
    JOIN weeks ON s.week_id = weeks.week_id
WHERE
    weeks.end_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-31') as q1
GROUP BY
    store_id
ORDER BY
    store_id```

| region | store_id | revenue | profit | %age | index |
-------------------------------------------------------
| north  | 01       | 2000    | 500    | 25   | 1.00  |
| north  | 02       | 1000    | 500    | 50   | 1.00  |
| north  | 03       | 3000    | 50     | 1.6  | 0.10  |
| south  | 04       | 4000    | 800    | 20   | 1.60  |
| south  | 05       | 1200    | 400    | 33   | 0.80  |
| south  | 06       | 800     | 200    | 25   | ...   |
| east   | 07       | 1800    | 450    | 25   | ...   |
| east   | 08       | 2200    | 1100   | 50   | ...   |
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select t1.*,
       t1.profit / sum(t1.profit) over() idx
  from (
SELECT 
    region, store_id, SUM(q1.revenue), SUM(q1.profit) as 'profit', 
    SUM(q1.profit) / SUM(revenue) * 100 as 'percentage'
FROM ( SELECT
    regions.region_name as 'region', s.store_id,
    s.revenue as 'revenue', (s.revenue - s.costs) as 'profit'
FROM
    store_sales s
    JOIN stores ON s.store_id = stores.store_id
    JOIN regions ON stores.store_id = regions.store_id
    JOIN weeks ON s.week_id = weeks.week_id
WHERE
    weeks.end_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-31') as q1
GROUP BY
    store_id
ORDER BY
    store_id
) t1
;
```

Comment: this is brilliant and does it exactly what I asked. Unfortunately, I discovered that I actually didn't phrase the question properly :( I actually need to compare the store profit to the average store profit for the region it's in. So store 1 should be 500 / avg(500,500,50). Hope that makes sense :D

Comment: `t1.profit / sum(t1.profit) over(partition by region) idx` @Sam Henderson

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks @nayi224

Answer (score 0):

You should be able do this by using a nested query that does the total profit sum:

```
... SUM(ql.profit) / (SELECT SUM(profit) FROM q1) ...
```

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts. However that is giving me an index of 1.00 for every row. Tried using SUM(profit) and also AVG(profit) but get the same result for each.....

Comment: Hmm, I did try this on one of my own data sets, and it worked, but I was selecting from a table, not from an aggregated subquery..  Now that I look at it, "SUM(q1.profit)" should be the same as "(SELECT(profit) FROM q1)", so this was a dumb idea to begin with.  I will think about it some more.